# Subgroup of O(2) isomorphic to $D_n$, matrices that form that group.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, orthogonal-matrices

I understand that any finite subgroup of O(2) must be isomorphic to either $D_n$ or $C_n$, (I also understand the proof of that fact.). However, I'm having trouble proving the following proposition, which is to find two matrices, say $A$ and $B$ such that every element of $G$, a subgroup of O(2) isomorphic to $D_n$, can be expressed as a product of $A$'s and $B$'s. 
I tried looking at the kernel of the morphism det:$G \rightarrow [{1,-1}]$, which is a normal subgroup of index 1 or 2, but I wasn't able to progress further.

What is the right path for this problem? Is there any new concepts that I need to know to solve this problem?

Comment: You could just try constructing elements explicitly. You know that $D_n$ contains an element of order $n$, but there are only a handful of elements of $O(2)$ with order $n$.

Comment: Would this just be an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $A^n = I$? If so, how does that help me find $A,B$ such that the subgroup must be constructable from products of As and Bs?

Comment: Not only $A^n = I$, but $A^k \neq I$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$. Put another way, we're looking for generators $A, B$ of the isomorphic copy of $D_n$ in $G$: We know what a generating set for $D_8$ is and the relations they satisfy; the usual choice is: $r, s$, $r^n = s^2 = 1$, $r s = s r^{n - 1}$. So, we're looking for $A, B \in O(2)$ that satisfy the same relations (and no others).

Answer (score 1):

By definition the question is asking for generators of the isomorphic copy of $D_n$ in $O(2)$.

**Hint** The usual generators for $D_n$ are $r, s$, satisfying $r^n = s^2 = 1$, $s r = r^{n - 1} s$. So, if we had an map $\phi : D_n \to O(2)$ that is an isomorphism to its image, we could declare $A := \phi(r)$: Then, since $r, s$ generate $D_n$, $A, B$ generate $\phi(D_n)$.

All elements in the nonidentity component $O(2) \setminus SO(2)$ have order $2$, so if $n > 2$, $\phi(r)$ must be in $SO(2)$, which we can identify with the unit circle group $S^1 \cong SO(2)$. Since $r$ has order $n$, so does $A = \phi(r)$.

> **Additional hint** As an element of $S^1$, $A$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, and the subgroup $\langle A \rangle$ comprises precisely the $n$th roots of unity. If we wish to be concrete, we may as well replace $A$ with the primitive root $\exp \frac{2 \pi i}{n}$, which under the usual isomorphism $S^1 \cong SO(2)$ corresponds to $$A = \pmatrix{\cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} & -\sin \frac{2 \pi}{n} \\ \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n} &  \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n}} .$$